# Выход из цикла while

Tags: c++, while

У меня есть конструкция

```
while(true){
   for(;;) {}
}
```

Как мне выйти из бесконечного цикла while внутри цикла for?

Comment: Дык `goto` же :)

Comment: Ещё throw, раз `C++`  в тэгах :)

Comment: @Outtruder setjmp еще можно - теоретически. Но пожалуйста, не надо!

Comment: Просто не надо создавать два глухих цикла (и интересно - почему снаружи `while`, а внутри `for`?), если всё-таки из них предполагается когда-то выйти. И переменные для проверки условия продолжения цикла - самый нормальный способ.

Comment: Старый эпический топик (больше 1000 постов) на эту тему - http://rsdn.ru/forum/philosophy/57977.flat.1

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 7):

К сожалению, в отличие от Джавы, C и C++ не поддерживают механизм вроде `break label`, поэтому самый чистый вариант — использовать goto:

```
int main() {
    while (true) {
        for (;;) {
            goto breakAll;
        }
    }

breakAll:
    puts("I'm out!");
}
```

Также можно использовать флаг:

```
int main() {
    bool running = true; // bool определен в stdbool.h
    while (running) {
        for (;;) {
            running = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    puts("I'm out!");
}
```

Большой разницы между этими вариантами нет.

Помимо этого случая, `goto` также используется в хорошем стиле C для обработки ошибок:

```
bars_t foo() {
    bar_t *bar1 = malloc(sizeof(*bar1));
    if (!bar1) {
        goto cleanupNothing;
    }

    bar_t *bar2 = malloc(sizeof(*bar2));
    if (!bar2) {
        goto cleanupBar1;
    }

    // ...

    return (bars_t) {
        .one = bar1,
        .two = bar2
    };

// в обратном порядке определения
cleanupBar2:
    free(bar2);
cleanupBar1:
    free(bar1);
cleanupNothing:
    return (bars_t){0};
}
```

В C++ подобное не нужно, т.к. есть RAII, но из циклов по-прежнему выходят через `goto`.

Comment: А тут, кстати, много меток и не надо, ибо `free()` лопает и NULL :-)

Answer (score 5):

Ещё добавлю пару способов.

Указанный код выносится в отдельную функцию. И теперь можно выходить по обычному `return`.

Способ два - нужно прост создать переменную флаг. И проверять ее. Где то так

```
bool go = true;
while(go){
   for(;;) { if (...) { go = false; break;}
}
```

Но это плохой способ.

Comment: Самый нормальный способ.

Comment: более того, он выходит с циклов любой вложенности:)

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    while (true)
    {
        for (;;) { throw 1; }
    }
}
catch (int)
{
    //вышли из двух вечных циклов одновременно
}
```

Comment: Какая-то эзотерика

Comment: Исключения следует использовать для *исключительных* ситуаций.

Comment: "Исключения следует использовать для исключительных ситуаций" - а разве выход сразу из двух вечных циклов это не исключительная ситуация?

Comment: @outcast: Нет. Это вполне обычная ситуация. Исключительная не значит «мне ни разу не попадалась», значит «в программе должна возникать в виде исключения, а не правила».

Comment: Выход из 2-х! бесконечных циклов это правило? Вот это да, никогда бы не подумал :)  Как не трудно заметить все альтернативные варианты либо предполагают изменение циклов, что очевидно противоречит изначальному условию (один из них перестает быть бесконечным), либо выглядят крайне сомнительно (вариант с goto). За исключением варианта с вынесением внутреннего цикла в отдельную функцию и пары return false/break, но это усложнит программу добавив в нее еще 1 сущность.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
while(1)
  {
  for(;;)
    {
    if(...)
      goto AWAY;
    }
  }

AWAY: ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inline bool func(){
    bool exit,only_break;   
    for(;;){        
        if(exit){
            return 1;
        }
        if(only_break){
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
    }
    int main(){
    while(1){
        if(func()){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```